# Kdenlive project stuck on 25 fps

Tags: framerate, kdenlive

I have a Kdenlive project that was started with 25 FPS and now I want to switch it to 30 FPS, but no matter what I do, it stays on 25 FPS and produces 25 FPS output files during rendering.

The title bar says 30 FPS, the project properties say 30 FPS, but when I open the `.kdenlive` file with a text editor the profile still says 25 FPS:

[image]

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<mlt LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8" producer="main_bin" root="Videos/Project" version="7.23.0">
 <profile colorspace="709" description="HD 1080p 25 fps" display_aspect_den="9" display_aspect_num="16" frame_rate_den="1" frame_rate_num="25" height="1080" progressive="1" sample_aspect_den="1" sample_aspect_num="1" width="1920"/>
 <producer id="producer0" in="00:00:00.000" out="00:00:45.600">
```

I even tried changing the profile by editing the `.kdenlive` file directly with an editor, but after loading it with Kdenlive it was back at 25 FPS.

Is there anything, short of creating a new project and arranging 100+ clips again to change this?

It doesn't matter if I open the project under Windows or Linux, I tested it with Kdenlive versions 24.02.1 and 22.12.3.